# How to separate date format literals when no separator is required

Tags: c#, vba, date, string-formatting, date-formatting

What date format string would you use in order to display consecutive date format literals so they are interpreted separately, as required?

As an example, if I wish to display March 31, 2016 as "201603Mar" - what date format string would I use?

Using "yyyyMMMMM" will not give the desired results, since "MMMMM" is translated to either "March" or "March3", depending on the implementation.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The trick is to use a separator that is not translated.  Which separator you use is determined by which programming language you are using.  As an example, here is the code for VBA and C#.

**VBA:**

```
Const strFormattedTimeFormat As String = "yyyyMM[]MMM"

Public Function strFormattedDate() As String
    strFormattedDate = Format(Date, strFormattedTimeFormat)
End Function
```

**C#:**

```
public static String strFormattedDate()
{
    const String sstrDateFormat = "yyyyMM''MMM";
    DateTime dtmLocalDate = DateTime.Now;

    return dtmLocalDate.ToString(sstrDateFormat);
}
```